# Actividad Javascript

Tags: javascript, bucle-for, condiciones

¿Cómo podría hacer que este programa muestre las diagonales en sentido contrario? Las diagonales, en este caso, las 'O'

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title></title>
</head> 
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">

/*asi debe quedar: 
***O
**O*
*O***/

var alto=prompt("Introduce el alto");
var ancho=prompt("Introduce el ancho");

for(var i=1;i<=alto;i++) {
    for(var j=1;j<=ancho;j++){
        if(i==j){
            document.write("O");
        }else{
            document.write("*");
        }
    }
    document.write("<br>");
}

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Cambiando esta linea:

```
for(var i=1;i<=alto;i++)
```

Por esta:

```
for(var i=alto;i>0;i--)
```

Answer (score 0):

Otra opción viable y más sencilla, es utilizar las funciones `padStart()` y `padEnd()` las cuales permiten completar una cadena a un largo específico, con un caracter elegido.
Una desde la izquierda y la otra hacia la derecha.

Con esto el código quedaría:

```js
var alto=prompt("Introduce el alto");
var ancho=prompt("Introduce el ancho");
var character = "O";

for(var i=0;i<alto;i++) {
    character = character.padStart(ancho-i, '*');
    character = character.padEnd(ancho, '*')

    document.write(character);
    document.write("<br>");
}
```